# Multi region latency based load balancing for lambdas in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, load-balancing, aws-api-gateway

I am working on deploying a Lambda on AWS, which will be accessed through API Gateway. I could deploy it on multiple regions if needed. I want to know if there is any way to load balance the calls to Lambdas based on geo-proximity.

I thought of creating a Route 53 geo-proximity rule, but it doesn't allows calling API gateway or Lambda functions.

Is there any way by which I could create a Global load balancer for my use case?

Thanks.

Comment: umm, wouldn't API gateway handle which lambda to call?

Comment: Related (not positive) conversation on the topic of using Route 53 latency-based routing in front of API Gateway: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220478. And somewhat more positive: http://blog.davestern.com/aws-latency-routing-with-api-gateway-and-haproxy/

Comment: Why do you plan for replication. Is it mainly for HA or to reduce Latency?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I need to route the calls to Lambda through a single point for all the regions, which is not possible using a single API gateway. Moreover, I need to distribute the calls to the lambdas based on geo-proximity.

Comment: @Ashan - It is mainly to reduce latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From November 2017 onwards, one has an option of creating a Regional API gateway instead of an Edge-optimized API gateway. The load balancing for the regional endpoint is explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-multi-region-serverless-application-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Lambd@Edge. It runs your Lambda functions at CloudFront edge locations so it’s executed close to your users.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html

Comment: Lambda edge might not fit to put your API Logic. It is mostly intended for request/response mediation operations in CloudFront.

Comment: Lambda Edge !== Lambda